# Passing hidden field value from view to controller with out using form concept

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass some hidden field from a view to a controller.

In **index.chtml**

```
<div id="root">
................
    @Html.Hidden("HProjectTypeId", "somevalue")
</div>
```

The above is not placed in any form like `Html.BeginForm` or **ajax form**. I need to get this value in action when loading itself.

If it is placed in a form it means we can get it easily from the `FormCollection` or `Request.Form["key"]`, but it is not placed in a form.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // here I need to get the hidden field "HProjectTypeId"
}
```

I am expecting some code in JQuery or JavaScript to do this.

thanks,

siva

Comment: If you are using jquery ajax. pass the value as parameter

Comment: no i dont want jquery.ajax. i am making full post (i.e. when loading the page first time itself)

Comment: It would be better if you could post some more code...

Comment: Sorry I m again clarifying - you want to pass hidden field value from view to controller when page first time loaded... not at submitting the form. right ???

Comment: yes krishna you are right

Answer (score 1):

The situation you're in isn't entirely clear (e.g. *why* isn't the hidden field within an `Html.BeginForm`?), but here's some suggestions:

Assuming the value you're writing into the hidden field comes from the server in the first place, how about not writing it into a hidden field at all, and using the `TempData` collection instead? The originating action sets the value, and it'll be persisted in session until the next request, making it available to the next action which is called

...or:

Assuming a form submission causes the Index action to be executed (as you are "making a full post"), you could use JavaScript to copy the hidden field's value into another hidden field which *is* included in an `Html.BeginForm`

...or:

Similarly, you could use JavaScript to write the hidden field's value into a cookie, and use a [custom ValueProvider for cookies](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/03/07/aspnet-mvc-working-smart-with-cookies-custom-valueprovider) to access it in your action.